# how to make ctrl+p behave exactly like up arrow in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

First of all, I am using zsh and [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) with nearly no other customization.

In zsh, when I press up-arrow, it brings me the latest commands. And if I typed some characters before I press up-arrow, it will bring me the latest command starting with those characters. It is quite an useful feature since I issue a lot of git/vim/scp commands alternatively.

But now I am switching to a keyboard without arrow keys, and I tend to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> instead of up-arrow for history completion. However, no matter how many characters I typed before press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, it will always bring me the latest command (not the latest starting with those characters)

How should I configure the zsh (or oh-my-zsh) to fix this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
bindkey "^P" up-line-or-search
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll file an issue to oh-my-zsh to add this into its default lib/keybinding.zsh.

Comment: You may want to add `bindkey "^N" down-line-or-search` as well for consistency.

Answer (score 10):

```
bindkey -e
```

This uses emacs keybindings and seems to work for me.

Comment: In your shell rc file `~/.zshrc`  if you set `export EDITOR=vim` then also key binding in shell will change to vim. In this case manually set key binding to emacs mode by `bindkey -e`